# Marking Integer points on plot in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, spyder

In the code below, I would like to mark the integer points.
I tried many options and different functions, but couldn't achieve the desired outcome.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = np.arange(-3,3,0.1)
x = n**2
plt.plot(n,x,'-ok')
```

The desired plot:
[image: desired plot]

Comment: Do you mean on axis or on the plot itself?

Comment: You have to start by asking a coherent question. The issue is not, as you may think, that English is likely not your first language, but that your question has very little actual information to go on. Please read an follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I add the photo it has to be like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an appraoch:

- use x-values in a dense linspace to draw the smooth curve
- use n-values of integers to draw the dots

A polynomial with integer coefficients gives integer values for all integer input.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x ** 2

x = np.linspace(-3.1, 3.1, 100)
plt.plot(x, f(x), '-r')
n = np.arange(-3, 4)
plt.plot(n, f(n), 'or')

plt.show()
```

To get a segmented line instead of a curve, both the line plot and the scatter plot could be done with only integer coordinates:

```py
n = np.arange(-3, 4)
plt.plot(n, f(n), '-r')
plt.plot(n, f(n), 'or')
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you so much I understood.